# Webpack add root path to automatically split chunks

Tags: webpack

Our team's project runs in a larger shell app, so all resource requests must begin with a path like

```
/project-123/
```

so the shell app knows to send the request to our server.

So for example, a JavaScript file might be

```
/project-123/js/bundle.12345.js
```

then (for example, at dev time) the shell would redirect that request to

```
localhost:1234/assets/js/bundle.12345.js
```

This becomes a problem when Webpack splits off chunks such as 1.js and 2.js automatically. When Webpack runtime asks for these modules at run time, it asks for

```
exampleshell.com/app/js/1.js
```

as oppose to

```
/project-123/js/1.js
```

so the shell is unable to understand the request and is unable to handle the request.

This is all outside of my control in a large team. But I can overwrite webpack config and change our team's own code.

How can I make Webpack runtime ask for

```
/project-123/js/1.js?
```

Comment: Could you upload your webpack config?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [output.publicPath](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath) parameter.